# List node of kubectl pod

Tags: redis, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have been following tutorial at https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/guestbook#step_four_create_the_redis_worker_service

After creating a pod (redis pod), when I tried to get the node

using the folloiwng command

```
  $ kubectl get pods -l name=redis-master -o wide
```

I don't see any output. It is just blank

Answer (score 0):

The name is a metadata, not a label in the example.

Try the following:

```
kubectl get pods -l app=redis,role=master -o wide
```